# Android startActivityForResult and child activity starts another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a scenario where I have my home screen (ActivityA) starting a login screen (ActivityB). This login screen will have a button to allow non-registered users to register an account, triggering (ActivityC).

In my code, I am having ActivityA

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
  ...
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class), 0);
  ...
}
```

and ActivityB

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
 ...
 startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityC.class));
 ...
}
```

Well it seems to work, but I'm concerned if there is any hidden problem that can possibly return to haunt me later? In ActivityB, if I start ActivityC, there is no setResult() call to trigger onActivityResult() of ActivityA. Is there any issue with such a flow, or should I be using startActivity instead of startActivityForResult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActivtyA's `onActivityResult` method will be triggered by ActivityB when it finishes. It doesn't matter what ActivityB does during its lifecycle or how many new Activities it spawns, when `finish()` is called on ActivityB (hopefully after calling `setResult()` it will propagate back to ActivityA. The only gap in your communication is that ActivityC can't tell ActivityB anything when it finishes. If you don't need that, you're fine; A and B's communication is still unaltered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Some questions in regards to your response 1) What happen if ActivityB does not even call finish()? 2)If ActivityC proceeds to startActivty() and start ActivityA, will there be any issue?

Comment: ActivityB will always have `finish()` called before it returns to ActivityA - it's in the lifecycle. If ActivityC starts ActivityA, it depends on how you start it. It should create a new instance so that your stack looks like "A B C A" in which case your result passage from B to A will still be fine. It's possible to launch A with flags to just bring it to the top of the stack, resulting in "B C A" in which case your result from B may be unused.